# Выпилить метку [layout]

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Есть предложение удалить метку [layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout). По ней находятся вопросы, которые связаны друг с другом очень отдаленно. А конкретно, там вопросы по [bootstrap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap), [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)+[css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и т. д.

Answer (score 4):

Очень много вопросов по Android, где ставят тег [layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout) вместо [android-layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout). Вопросы связанные с Android'ом все поправил. Осталось 44 вопроса с этой меткой.